# auth_basic together with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I have a VoIP phone, which is running web server for management and settings. This phone is behind a Nginx proxy.

Now, there are two problems. VoIP phone's web server is using HTTPS but with SSL 3.0. And it has default username `admin` and password `22222` which cannot be changed.

So what I did?

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name _;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass https://192.168.100.51;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
     }
}
```

This is solving first problem - I am connecting to Nginx proxy with TLS 1.2, and connection is then re-encrypted by Nginx to old and insecure SSL 3.0 to a VoIP phone behind the proxy.

Also, I am not sure if I really need `root`, `index` and `server_name` directives, so please advise me on that.

But how to change authentication? I tried to add:

```
auth_basic "VoIP phone";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
```

...but web browser keeps asking me for authentication. Unless, I set username `admin` and password `22222`.

I was also checking logs, and Nginx actually accepted my new username and a password (not saying that user does not exists or there is a password mismatch), but it still keeps asking for authentication for a mobile phone.

I also tried to login as `newadmin:newpassword` first and then `admin:22222`, but this doesn't work neither.

I was thinking to enter `Authorization` header manually inside `location` (`proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic YWRtaW46MjIyMjIK";`), but it is also not working.

(`YWRtaW46MjIyMjIK` is `admin:22222` Base64 encoded.)

Any other idea?

Also, what if I would like to "disable" authentication to VoIP phone completely (so that authentication will be done by Nginx proxy)?

Comment: Using `proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic YWRtaW46MjIyMjIK";` should work. And you can combine your own basic auth (`auth_basic "VoIP phone"; auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;`) with the `proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic YWRtaW46MjIyMjIK";` directive going next. I just tested this scenario on two chained nginx servers (each having its own basic auth database) and it works as expected.

Comment: Indeed. I also made a mistake by generating Base64 encoded string - in encoding newline was included. Correct encoding procedure is: `echo -n "admin:22222" | base64`. This returns: `YWRtaW46MjIyMjI=` and now it is working.

Comment: And answering your second question - _Also, I am not sure if I really need `root`, `index` and `server_name` directives, so please advise me on that._ - you can safely omit those directives.